# Find overlap between series of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 series of numbers as follow

[image]

For each line I need to find the overlaping ranges. So using the table above the overlap is as follow :

[image]

Right now, my series are stored in collection as follow :

[image]

And I would like to output a collection like this : Though it could be ok with a different structure as well

[image]

And to make thing even more complicated I can have some extrem cases where serie A contain series B and C like so :

[image]

So in that case I guess output need to be as follow :

[image]

So I naturally started trying nested loops but I just can't get the result I want. Some help, even just pointers, would much appreciated.

Comment: Please include your vba code and explain where stuck. Please insert data as tables rather than images using [edit]. You will see `Tables` appear as an option along the edit bar to the right hand side.

Comment: @QHer Why insert data as tables rather than images? .. This looks quite clear to me. Tables are so complicated to do in stackoverflow. Is there an easy way?

Comment: 1) Tables are easy to do - at least should be given new functionality to support that. Otherwise,  use a 3rd party online free markdown table generator 2) We cannot copy paste from images for testing (partic a problem where lots of data) 3) Not everyone can view images e.g. some on mobile devices  . [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) , [table generators](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) - just copy paste  from Excel - when insert generated table into question, highlight entire table and press Ctrl + K, same as with code.

Comment: I use that latter method. Copy table from Excel into generator, press generate markdown, copy paste into question, highlight the table and press Ctrl + K

Comment: Are the numbers always integers, and are they bounded (min max values)?

Comment: @QHarr That's a really cool tip. Thanks!

Comment: @JAlex yes always integers and between 50.000 to 60.000 roughly. Usually, all numbers form the same line are within 500 from each other at the maximum.

Comment: @QHarr thank you for the tip I will update it tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Comment: The key tables are those containing input/start data and output/desired end state data.

Comment: Is the 'from' column always sorted, or can a row define a range smaller than the row above it?

Comment: It can be smaller than the row above. I managed to come up with a code that gives me the result I want just now. I will make it "Stack Overflow friendly" and post it in a moment.

Comment: How is the code activated? is there a button, or does it hook to an workbook or worksheet event?

Comment: Are all the series (A,B,C etc) have the _same_ number of rows?

Comment: The code is activated every time a change is made in the series or a line is added through a worksheet change event. Yes all the series have the same number of rows. I posted my code in an answer. Would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : I edited my code because in the case where for example Serie B is from 45 to 59 and Serie C from 55 to 60, it would not pick up the last range 60, 60, C

As I mentionned in a comment above I have something working. Here is the details :

First, I check if there is any overlap or not with the following function :

```
Public Function F_CollOverlap(CollA As Collection, CollB As Collection, CollC As Collection) As Collection
'CollA
'   Item1 = represent a line
'       Item1 = Always smaller than Item2
'       Item2 = Always bigger than Item1
' CollA, B and C always have the same number of Items
    Dim c
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CollTemp As New Collection
        For i = 1 To CollA.Count
            If CollA(i)(2) < CollC(i)(1) Or CollA(i)(1) > CollC(i)(2) Then
                If CollA(i)(2) < CollB(i)(1) Or CollA(i)(1) > CollB(i)(2) Then
                    If CollB(i)(2) < CollC(i)(1) Or CollB(i)(1) > CollC(i)(2) Then
                        CollTemp.Add "False"
                    Else
                        CollTemp.Add "True"
                    End If
                Else
                    CollTemp.Add "True"
                End If
            Else
                CollTemp.Add "True"
            End If
        Next
    Set F_CollOverLap = CollTemp
End Function
```

Then, the following function will give me the result I want :

```
Public Function F_CollRngOverlap(CollOverlap As Collection, CollA As Collection, CollB As Collection, CollC As Collection) As Collection
    Dim c, i, j
    Dim CollTemp As New Collection
    Dim CollTemp2 As New Collection
    Dim CollNum As New Collection
    Dim CollType As New Collection
    Dim CollRanges As New Collection
    Dim Amin As Long, Amax As Long, Bmin As Long, Bmax As Long, Cmin As Long, Cmax As Long
    
            For i = 1 To CollA.Count
                If CollOverlap(i) Then
                    Amin = CollA(i)(1)
                    Amax = CollA(i)(2)
                    Bmin = CollB(i)(1)
                    Bmax = CollB(i)(2)
                    Cmin = CollC(i)(1)
                    Cmax = CollC(i)(2)
                    For j = WorksheetFunction.Min(Amin, Bmin, Cmin) To WorksheetFunction.max(Amax, Bmax, Cmax)
                        If Within(j, Amin, Amax) And Within(j, Bmin, Bmax) And Within(j, Cmin, Cmax) Then
                            CollNum.Add j
                            CollType.Add "abc"
                        ElseIf Within(j, Amin, Amax) And Within(j, Bmin, Bmax) Then
                            CollNum.Add j
                            CollType.Add "ab"
                        ElseIf Within(j, Bmin, Bmax) And Within(j, Cmin, Cmax) Then
                            CollNum.Add j
                            CollType.Add "bc"
                        ElseIf Within(j, Amin, Amax) And Within(j, Cmin, Cmax) Then
                            CollNum.Add j
                            CollType.Add "ac"
                        ElseIf Within(j, Amin, Amax) Then
                            CollNum.Add j
                            CollType.Add "a"
                        ElseIf Within(j, Bmin, Bmax) Then
                            CollNum.Add j
                            CollType.Add "b"
                        ElseIf Within(j, Cmin, Cmax) Then
                            CollNum.Add j
                            CollType.Add "c"
                        End If
                    Next
                    For j = 1 To CollNum.Count
                        If j = 1 Then
                            CollTemp.Add CollNum(j)
                        ElseIf CollType(j) <> CollType(j - 1) Then
                            If j = CollNum.Count Then
                                CollTemp.Add CollNum(j - 1)
                                CollTemp.Add CollType(j - 1)
                                CollTemp2.Add CollTemp
                                Set CollTemp = Nothing
                                CollTemp.Add CollNum(j)
                                CollTemp.Add CollNum(j)
                                CollTemp.Add CollType(j)
                                CollTemp2.Add CollTemp
                                Set CollTemp = Nothing
                            Else
                                CollTemp.Add CollNum(j - 1)
                                CollTemp.Add CollType(j - 1)
                                CollTemp2.Add CollTemp
                                Set CollTemp = Nothing
                                CollTemp.Add CollNum(j)
                            End If
                        ElseIf j = CollNum.Count Then
                            CollTemp.Add CollNum(j)
                            CollTemp.Add CollType(j)
                            CollTemp2.Add CollTemp
                            Set CollTemp = Nothing
                        End If
                    Next
                    CollRanges.Add CollTemp2
                    Set CollTemp2 = Nothing
                    Set CollNum = Nothing
                    Set CollType = Nothing
                    Set CollTemp = Nothing
                Else
                    CollTemp.Add CollA(i)
                    CollTemp(1).Add "a"
                    CollTemp.Add CollB(i)
                    CollTemp(2).Add "b"
                    CollTemp.Add CollC(i)
                    CollTemp(3).Add "c"
                    CollRanges.Add CollTemp
                    Set CollTemp = Nothing
                End If
            Next
    Set F_CollRngOverlap = CollRanges
End Function
```

It's also using the following function :

```
Public Function Within(ByVal Number As Long, ByVal lowerbound As Long, ByVal upperbound As Long) As Boolean
    If Number >= lowerbound And Number <= upperbound Then
        Within = True
    Else
        Within = False
    End If
End Function
```

You can test it with this sub :

```
Sub test()
Dim CollA As New Collection
Dim CollB As New Collection
Dim CollC As New Collection
Dim CollTemp As New Collection
Dim CollOverlap As New Collection
Dim CollRngOverlap As New Collection
Dim i As Long
Dim smallrandom As Long
Dim bigrandom As Long

    For i = 1 To 15
        smallrandom = Int(50 * Rnd) + 1
        bigrandom = Int(50 * Rnd) + smallrandom
        CollTemp.Add smallrandom
        CollTemp.Add bigrandom
        CollA.Add CollTemp
        Set CollTemp = Nothing
    Next
    For i = 1 To 15
        smallrandom = Int(50 * Rnd) + 1
        bigrandom = Int(50 * Rnd) + smallrandom
        CollTemp.Add smallrandom
        CollTemp.Add bigrandom
        CollB.Add CollTemp
        Set CollTemp = Nothing
    Next
    For i = 1 To 15
        smallrandom = Int(50 * Rnd) + 1
        bigrandom = Int(50 * Rnd) + smallrandom
        CollTemp.Add smallrandom
        CollTemp.Add bigrandom
        CollC.Add CollTemp
        Set CollTemp = Nothing
    Next
    
    Set CollOverlap = F_CollOverlap(CollA, CollB, CollC)
    Set CollRngOverlap = F_CollRngOverlap(CollOverlap, CollA, CollB, CollC)
End Sub
```

Comment: You posted this message as an answer. Is this really an answer to your problem? If you just wanted to add more info, you should have *edited* your post. People who waht to help may not read this if it's not in the question section.

Comment: Yes it's an answer to my initial question. I'm pretty sure there is a more straight forward/Clear way to do it but this is what I've got. Anyway I will accept this answer as solution once I can (still 3 hours before StackOverflow will let me)